# Oracle query to SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-query-store

What is the equivalent sql sever query for

```
SELECT Table_Name,
       Column_Name,
       Data_Type,
       Data_Length,
       Data_Precision,
       Data_Scale, Nullable,
       Character_Set_Name,
       Char_Col_Decl_Length,
       Char_Length
FROM all_tab_cols ORDER BY Table_Name, Column_Id
```

Comment: Exactly the same...

Comment: If you are looking for `Sql Server` then `information_schema.columns` or `sys.syscolumns` would do.

Comment: If you want query for SQL Server, you need to edit you question to ask equivalent `TSQL` query.

Comment: I had mentioned it in the heading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a standard sql query syntax!

Comment: does all_tab_cols exist in sql?

Comment: maybe all_tab_cols is the name of the table?

Answer (score 2):

May be this is what you are looking for..

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA ,TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME
,ORDINAL_POSITION,COLUMN_DEFAULT,IS_NULLABLE,DATA_TYPE 
,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH,COLLATION_NAME
,*
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: What about the Character_Set_Name,
       Char_Col_Decl_Length,
       Char_Length fields??

Comment: Since everything is available in that table, I've included * in the query. See edited answer @AnishAravind

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
information_schema.columns
```

Which will select most of what you have asked for, then your WHERE and ORDER BY conditions are done in the usual way.

**EDIT**:

For those asking, using "all_tab_cols" in a SQL server FROM condition throws an invalid object error, unless the user defines it as something. The above how this is achieved in SQL server.

Comment: What about the Character_Set_Name, Char_Col_Decl_Length, Char_Length fields??

Comment: @Anish Aravind CHARACTER_SET_NAME is there, Char_length is called CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH which is the length in characters. Char_Col_Decl_Length I think is similar to CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH which is the length in bytes.